# Unable to save values into sql server database. no error in my code

Tags: android, mysql, database

i have an application that should save values in a sql server database but when i check in my database no data is saved and my code does not show error.please review my code and correct errors accordingly. thank you

feedback.java

```
package com.IwayAfrica.feedback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;


public class feedback extends Activity
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputcomment;
    RadioGroup sorted;
    RadioGroup ambiance;
    RadioGroup rooms;
    RadioGroup food;
    RadioGroup reception;
    Button buttonsave;
    int success = 0;
    String sort = "";
    String room = "";
    String foods = "";
    String amb = "";
    String rec = "";

    private static String url_register_user = "http://http://localhost/IwayAfrica%20Feedback/processs.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.feedback);

        inputcomment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);

        Button buttonsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

        final RadioGroup sorted = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.sorted);
        final RadioButton yes1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yes1);
        final RadioButton no1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.no1);
        final RadioButton par = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.par);

        final RadioGroup ambiance = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.ambiance);
        final RadioButton fast = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fast);
        final RadioButton fasten = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fasten);
        final RadioButton slow = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.slow);

        final RadioGroup rooms = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rooms);
        final RadioButton reyes = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.reyes);
        final RadioButton reno = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.reno);
        final RadioButton remaybe = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.remaybe);

        final RadioGroup food = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.food);
        final RadioButton fdbest = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fdbest);
        final RadioButton fdgood = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fdgood);
        final RadioButton fdfair = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fdfair);
        final RadioButton fdpoor = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fdpoor);

        final RadioGroup reception = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.reception);
        final RadioButton rsbest = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rsbest);
        final RadioButton rsgood = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rsgood);
        final RadioButton rsfair = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rsfair);
        final RadioButton rspoor = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rspoor);

        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 String comment = inputcomment.getText().toString();

                 if (sorted.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == yes1.getId())
                 {
                      sort = "100";
                 }
                 else if (sorted.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == par.getId())
                 {
                      sort = "60";
                 }
                 else if (sorted.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == no1.getId())
                 {
                      sort = "30";
                 }


                 if (ambiance.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fast.getId())
                 {
                      amb = "100";
                 }
                 else if (ambiance.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fasten.getId())
                 {
                      amb = "60";
                 }
                 else if (ambiance.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == slow.getId())
                 {
                      amb = "30";
                 }


                 if (rooms.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == reyes.getId())
                 {
                      room = "100";
                 }
                 else if (rooms.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == remaybe.getId())
                 {
                      room = "60";
                 }
                 else if (rooms.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == reno.getId())
                 {
                      room = "30";
                 }


                 if (food.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fdbest.getId())
                 {
                      foods = "100";
                 }
                 else if (food.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fdgood.getId())
                 {
                      foods = "75";
                 }
                 else if (food.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fdfair.getId())
                 {
                      foods = "50";
                 }
                 else if (food.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == fdpoor.getId())
                 {
                      foods = "25";
                 }


                 if (reception.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rsbest.getId())
                 {
                      rec = "100";
                 }
                 else if (reception.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rsgood.getId())
                 {
                     rec = "75";
                 }
                 else if (reception.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rsfair.getId())
                 {
                     rec = "50";
                 }
                 else if (reception.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rspoor.getId())
                 {
                     rec = "25";
                 }



                     new RegisterNewUser().execute();

            } 
        });
    }


      public void gotomain(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }


class RegisterNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{


       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
           String comment = inputcomment.getText().toString();


           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sort", sort));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amb", amb));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("room", room));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rec", rec));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foods", foods));

           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_user,
                   "POST", params);

           // check log cat fro response
           Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

           // check for success tag
           try {
               int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

               if (success == 1) {
                   // successfully created product
                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), main.class);
                   startActivity(i);

                   // closing this screen
                   finish();
               } else {
                   // failed to create product
               }
           } catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;

       }


   }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.IwayAfrica.feedback;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

processs.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['sort']) && isset($_POST['amb']) && isset($_POST['room']) && isset($_POST['foods']) && isset($_POST['rec']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {

    $problem=$_POST['sort'];
    $time=$_POST['amb'];
    $reccomend=$_POST['room'];
    $rate1=$_POST['foods'];
    $rate2=$_POST['rec'];
    $improve=$_POST['comment'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feedback (problem,time,reccomend,rate1,rate2,improve)              VALUES('$problem','$time','$reccomend','$rate1','$rate2','$improve')";

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "feedback successfull.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a pile of code. Post relevant parts.

Comment: at least try and specify where YOU might think the error would be

Comment: remember to correct his errors accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things come to mind:

1) Check your connect.php file. I would bet that the either the name, password or user of your database is wrong.

2) Check that the table column names and the table name are spelled correctly.

3) Encode the error in your result array so you can read what it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$problem=$_POST['sort'];
$time=$_POST['amb'];
$reccomend=$_POST['room'];
$rate1=$_POST['foods'];
$rate2=$_POST['rec'];
$improve=$_POST['comment'];
```

why you not declare $problem = $_POST['problem'];

for me your file so confusing.

then you must try that php file was success. Try to execute from your browser. if not success,that is something wrong with your php.

for radio button,try this http://nsafaat.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/form-master-entry-data-ke-mysql-server-berbasis-android/.

it's work for me.

Comment: i tired all what you said but it the emulator displays error message application has stopped unexpectedly